# mdframed: option thmmarks of ntheorem affects vertical skip after theorem

Tags: mdframed, ntheorem

I define a framed theorem environment with the mdframed package.

I experience the following problem: There is no vertical skip between the bottom of the frame and the text of the following paragraph if the framed theorem is split across pages.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}%
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{mdfStyle}{%
   innerleftmargin=0.5\parindent,%
   innerrightmargin=0pt,%
   innertopmargin=0.5\parindent,%
   innerbottommargin=0.5\parindent,
   topline=true,%
   rightline=false,%
   bottomline=true,%
   leftline=true,%
   roundcorner=3pt,%
   linewidth=1pt,
   linecolor=black,
   ntheorem=true}

\newmdtheoremenv[style=mdfStyle]{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[2]
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[3]
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[5]
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

An uninspired workaround is to replace

```
\mdfdefinestyle{mdfStyle}{%
   innerleftmargin=0.5\parindent,%
   innerrightmargin=0pt,%
   innertopmargin=0.5\parindent,%
   innerbottommargin=0.5\parindent,
   topline=true,%
   rightline=false,%
   bottomline=true,%
   leftline=true,%
   roundcorner=3pt,%
   linewidth=1pt,
   linecolor=black,
   ntheorem=true}
```

with

```
\mdfdefinestyle{mdfStyle}{%
   innerleftmargin=0.5\parindent,%
   innerrightmargin=0pt,%
   innertopmargin=0.5\parindent,%
   innerbottommargin=0.5\parindent,
   topline=true,%
   rightline=false,%
   bottomline=true,%
   leftline=true,%
   roundcorner=3pt,%
   linewidth=1pt,
   linecolor=black,
   ntheorem=true,%
   afterlastframe={\vspace{\topsep}}}
```

Question 1: Is this a bug?

Question 2: Is there a better workaround that adds vertical space only if "needed"?

Note: The problem does not arise without the option thmmarks to ntheorem.

Comment: Given that `mdframed` tries to cope with `ntheorem` I guess this could be regarded as a bug.  Your work around code does not work for me and I have not found an alternative.